# LINQ Left Join with wrong response

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to do a left join using LINQ.

I'm using this code:

```
 var query = (from Geral in listEstadosGeral
                     join Coberto in listEstadoCoberto
                         on Geral.Id equals Coberto.Id
                         into temp
                     from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new Estado()
                     {
                         Sigla = Geral.Sigla,
                         Nome = Geral.Nome

                     }).ToList();
```

In listEstadoGeral I have 27 records and in listEstadoCoberto I have 5 records.

The query has 27 records.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: is that 5 records different from the first tables 27 records? I assume, you got 27 records because 5 records matched the id with 27 records.

Comment: They have the same id.

Comment: then the behavior is expected. Since they have the same id, the Result set should have all 27 rows, even if you would have used left join with no ids matching, the result will be 27 only.

Comment: @b3r3ch1t Problem is not specified in the question clearly.Please be specific so that specific solution is given.

Comment: *In listEstadoGeral I have 27 records and in listEstadoCoberto I have 5 records. The query has 27 records.* This is exactly the expected result of a `left outer join`. Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the records that are present in listEstadosGeral that are not in listEstadoCoberto :

```
var result = listEstadosGeral.Where(p => !listEstadoCoberto.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var query = (from Geral in listEstadosGeral
                 join Coberto in listEstadoCoberto
                 on Geral.Id equals Coberto.Id                       
                 select new Estado()
                 {
                     Sigla = Geral.Sigla,
                     Nome = Geral.Nome
                 }).ToList();
```